# OpenModelica: the file "_info.xml" created after simulation is too big. How reduce it?

Tags: xml, size, openmodelica

I created a tool using ".xml" and ".exe" files generated by OpenModelica after a simulation (_init.xml, _info.xml and .exe). This tool has an userfriendly Excel interface to manage this model already compiled.

My problem is the size of the files generated, especially the "_info.xml" which is too big (120 Mo). The Modelica model is of course big too (25000 variables due to discretisation part of the model).

Why this file so big (Many description of variables are repeated and seem useless)? Any tips to reduce the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent OpenModelica versions produce a _info.json file, which is often much smaller. Not using -d=infoXmlOperations will also reduce its size a lot (at the cost of removing a lot of useful information for debugging and analysis).

Comment: Good. I already disable the infoXmlOperations which generate a folder twice bigger. But the new version of OpenModelica generate a "_info.json" twice smaller in my case and it works well for me.